# Where does Wordpress keep the relationship between image ID, and the image source?

Tags: wordpress

I'm exploring the Wordpress gallery functionality, and i see that each "gallery" is basically represented as a shortcode in the text editor, containing the id's of all selected images.

I didn't manage to find anything in the WP database, that implies this connection. Can anybody tell me where exactly this src-id relationship is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image uploaded to the Wordpress media library is tracked in the `wp_posts` table with a `post_type` of `attachment`. You can find it by looking at the attachment ID in the URL when browsing the Media Library (e.g. `/wp-admin/upload.php?item=12345`

The corresponding image source is then stored in the table `wp_postmeta`. You can search for an attachment's metadata (or image source) by looking for the attachment ID in the `post_id` column.

Comment: Nice, that you. I must say i find it a bit funny, that Wordpress treats everything as a "post". It's so different than what i got used to. But then, the reason for that is probably rooted in the fact that Wordpress developed from a blog system, to a full CMS